# How to change one of the attribute reference to anchor in ruamel.yaml

Tags: merge, anchor, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml in my project and have a YAML document which uses anchor, there are multiple places reference to that anchor. I want to change one of the attribute of one of the places which reference to anchor without touch the others.

The following code shows in detail what I want to do.

```
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml_str = """\
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params: *foo
"""
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data["anotherbar"]["params"]["length"] = 39
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

The above code will output

```
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 39
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params: *foo
```

I want to change params in "anotherbar", but it changes "bar" as well.

And if I copy the params before assign new value, it will work but it also copy the other params which I don't want to change:

```
data["anotherbar"]["params"] = data["anotherbar"]["params"].copy()
data["anotherbar"]["params"]["length"] = 39
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

outputs:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params:
    color: red
    length: 39
    weight: 32.3
```

But I actually want the following YAML without anything duplicated:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params:
    <<: *foo
    length: 39
```

How can I get this merge key programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruamel.yaml can round-trip the output that you want:

```
import sys
import io
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params:
    <<: *foo
    length: 39
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
buf = io.StringIO()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, buf)
assert buf.getvalue() == yaml_str
```

so it is possible to construct that output from your
actual input, but there is no built-in routine to do so.

```
params = data["anotherbar"]["params"]
print(type(params))
print(params.merge)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>
[(0, ordereddict([('color', 'red'), ('length', 599), ('weight', 32.3)]))]
```

That "ordereddict", is actualy the `data["foo"]` object.

Instead of copying, you need to create the special dictionary type ruamel.yaml
uses internally and then hook up the merge key and set the key/value, and attach this
in the data tree.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params: *foo
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

upd = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()  # empty dict like type
data["anotherbar"]["params"] = upd         # attach it to the data
upd.add_yaml_merge([(0, data["foo"])])     # attach original dict as merge
upd["length"] = 39                         # set the value you want
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives what you want:

```
foo: &foo
  color: red
  length: 599
  weight: 32.3

bar:
  name: bar_one
  params: *foo

anotherbar:
  name: bar_another
  params:
    <<: *foo
    length: 39
```

The `add_yaml_merge` is an internal routine used by the construction phase of
the loading. It can change without notice so make sure to pin your version of
ruamel.yaml in a production environment.